# How to create a collection view with images that change size on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to implement an horizontal collection view displaying images that increases the size of the images with a smooth animation as they approach the center and reduces their size as they move away.

[image]

I have been studying the UICollectionView potentials but so far I have not been able to understand if such behaviour is possible to be implemented using UICollectionView or what would be the best alternative. For instance using UIScrollView instead (with a lot more work probably).

Some guidance or sample code would be most welcome. Thank you.

Comment: It was on WWDC when `UICollectionView` was introduced.

Comment: Can [this](https://medium.com/@sh.soheytizadeh/zoom-uicollectionview-centered-cell-swift-5-e63cad9bcd49) help you ?